# One click forward marked messages. AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I have an AppleScript whose task is to forward flagged messages to another email (in the standard Apple Mail application), but it does not work as I need. I added this script to the Automator as a service.

I have to
1) flag the message.
2) go to the services and select the "Forward marked messages" service that I need, and only then they are forwarded all at once.

My idea is to auto forward a incoming message to the assistant immediately after marked the message with a flag.
Could someone correct my AppleScript?
Or am I mistaken in introducing it into services?

Help me please!

```
set toAddress to "alex@example.com"
set toName to "Alex"

tell application "Mail"
    repeat with _acct in imap accounts
        --Look For Flagged Messages in the INBOX
        set _acct_name to name of _acct
        set _inbox to _acct's mailbox "INBOX"
        set _msgs_to_capture to (a reference to ¬
            (every message of _inbox ¬
                whose flagged status is true))

        repeat with _msg in _msgs_to_capture
            set _fwdmsg to forward _msg with opening window

            tell _fwdmsg
                make new to recipient at end of ¬
                    to recipients with properties {name:toName, address:toAddress}
            end tell

            activate

            send _fwdmsg
        end repeat
    end repeat
end tell
```